# Random data simulator using Azure Mobile Services

Tags: windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to implement a device with a few sensors that will send their values in an Azure database using an WP8 app and Azure Mobile Services. While the hardware part will be done, I want to somehow simulate this whole process. Meaning that I want to have an app that will generate some random values at an interval of 1s and upload these values in the cloud.

So my question is: what would be the best approach to do this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create Sensors Reader abstraction layer. In the release version, you'll read the real data, but in the test version you can generate data or receive the data over the network (for example) from the generator app. Azure db have the local simulator too. So, I see no problem in your case.

Comment: I was also expecting some suggestions on how to start implement this on Windows Phone 8, but thanks anyway.